# Is there a tutorial for beginners on capsule neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, reference-request, resource-request, capsule-neural-network

I am interested in capsule neural networks. I have already read the paper [Dynamic Routing Between Capsules](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.09829), but it is a little bit difficult to follow. Is there a tutorial for beginners on capsule neural networks?